# How to stream in the contents of a file in C# directly to args?

Tags: c#

I have a solution that reads the command line for a file name and read its contents. I just realized that it would be neat if i could go

```
c:\MyReader.exe < text.txt
```

instead of

```
c:\MyReader.exe text.txt
```

if the contents of the file got placed as the `args` input in `Main(String[] args)`. Is it doable or will i have to parse the file anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This wouldn't put the contents into `args`, but rather [redirect it to standard input](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true) so the `Console.Read` methods would read from the file instead of the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

As you have undoubtedly found out, redirect would not work. An ability to do what you are trying to achieve depends on the capabilities of your shell interpreter. You can almost certainly write a batch file that does what you want, but you could as well make it a feature of your own program, rather than relying on batch files.

```
public static Main(String[] args) {
    if (args.Length >= 2 && args[0] == "/args") {
        args = File.ReadAllText(args[1]).Split(' ');
    }
    ...
}
```

If your program is started like this:

```
c:\MyReader.exe /args text.txt
```

the arguments would be taken from `text.txt`; if your program is started like this:

```
c:\MyReader.exe param1 param2 param3
```

then the arguments would be whatever is passed on the command line.